# how can I sort RDD data (key, value) by value in Scala?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

I have tried the method "`sortBy`" like this:

`ranks.sortBy(x=> x._2, false);`

However, the ranks' value do not sorted, details is showed in the picture.
[my failed solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OADo.png)

So how should I correct my solutions? Why does it fail?
Thanks for help!

Comment: `sortBy` will return your sorted result, so you need to assign the result to some variable and then use that variable. Just use `val sortedRes = ranks.sortBy()` and then `sortedRes` will have sorted result.

Comment: Complementing @vindev comment/answer - in Spark _(and in Scala in general)_ we prefer immutability. Thus, it is pretty common that any method that seems to mutate some data, in reality is just returning a copy of the data with the _"mutation"_ (**Transformation**) applied. For that reason, unless the method returns `Unit` (i.e. it is completely imperative, e.g. `saveAsTextFile` or `foreach`), you always assign the return of call to other variable and continue your computation with that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `ranks` is a `var` in your scenario.

When you call `ranks.sortBy...`, you are not assigning this to any variable - you are just asking the compiler to sortBy something and throwing the result away.

You just need to assign this to a variable and it should work (`ranks = ranks.sortBy(...)` or `val something = ranks.sortBy(...)`). Here's a quick example in a REPL:

```
scala> var l = List(3, 1, 2)
l: List[Int] = List(3, 1, 2)

scala> l.sortBy(x => x)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l // will be the same as before
res2: List[Int] = List(3, 1, 2)

scala> l = l.sortBy(x => x)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l // will have changed
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```